# How to approach (MySQL Query): Only find newest rows by DISTINCT WHERE the newst one IS NOT a specific value (with symfony2)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I worked and read for hours and I can't find any proper solution besides doing unperformad querys or adding new fields and update events to my code. As you can imagine this problem is driving me nuts.

**Base Idea**

I do have a table called **`ping`** which contains information about the response time of website and is in the ManyToOne relation to `website`.
Another table called **`website`** contains data about the website and is in oneToMany relation to `ping`.
Therefore a `website` can have thouands of pings, but a `ping` row can only have one website.
So far so good.

**Table Data**
**`table: ping`** - with one example row:

```
=================================================================================
|      id       |  website_id   |   response    | is_reachable  |  created_at   |
=================================================================================
|     6994      |      15       |      49       |       1       |  22/12/2013   |
|               |               |               |               |   12:14:23    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**`table: website`** - with one example row:

```
=================================================================================================
|      id       |  company_id   |     name      |      url      |     logo      |  description  |
=================================================================================================
|      15       |       7       |   LinkedIn    |http://www.link| linkedin.svg  |  US Website   |
|               |               |               |   edin.com    |               |               |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**Case**

What I want to do is make a simple list of the last 10 slowest responses (ms). Sounds easy? Maybe I got the wrong database design or I just don't see the point.
Anyhow I need to **filter out** those who are **NOT** reachable (`is_reachable = 0` or/and `response=null`) but this can't be done by a `WHERE` clause as this would show me the LAST `ping row` which `is_reachable = 1` which is not my aim.

As far as I came was this:

```
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
            ->Select('DISTINCT(s.website)')
            ->AddSelect('s.id, s.response')
            ->AddSelect('w.id as wid, w.name')
            ->leftJoin("s.website", 'w')
            ->orderBy('s.id', 'DESC')
            ->addorderBy('s.response, 'DESC');
```

which produces so far this:

```
array (size=10)
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      1 => string '21' (length=2)
      'id' => int 14063
      'response' => int 75
      'wid' => int 21
      'name' => string 'Google Mail' (length=11)
  1 => 
    array (size=5)
      1 => string '20' (length=2)
      'id' => int 14062
      'response' => int 27
      'wid' => int 20
      'name' => string 'Google DE' (length=9)
  2 => 
    array (size=5)
      1 => string '19' (length=2)
      'id' => int 14061
      'response' => int 25
      'wid' => int 19
      'name' => string 'Google' (length=6)
  3 => 
    array (size=5)
      1 => string '18' (length=2)
      'id' => int 14060
      'response' => null
      'wid' => int 18
      'name' => string 'Twitter DE' (length=10)
  4 => 
    array (size=5)
      1 => string '17' (length=2)
      'id' => int 14059
      'response' => null
      'wid' => int 17
      'name' => string 'Twitter UK' (length=10)
```

As mentioned above if you would add a simple `WHERE` statement this would just cause that TWITTER DE/TWITTER UK show their last row with `is_reachable=1`.
I have no clue how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated!

**TEMP SOULTION (SERACHING FOR BETTER ONE!)**

```
$em = $this->getEntityManager();
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
$rsm->addScalarResult('website_id', 'website_id');
$rsm->addScalarResult('name', 'name');
$rsm->addScalarResult('response', 'response');
$query = $em->createNativeQuery(
    "
    select inf.website_id, w.name, inf.response, inf.is_reachable, inf.max_date
    from (
        select p.website_id, p.response, p.id, p.is_reachable, lp.max_date
        from ping p
        inner join (
            select website_id, max(created_at) as max_date
            from ping
            group by website_id
            ) lp
        on lp.website_id = p.website_id
        and lp.max_date = p.created_at
        ) inf, website w
    where inf.website_id = w.id
    and inf.is_reachable != 0
    order by inf.response ".$orderBy."
    LIMIT ?
    ", $rsm)
    ->setParameter(1, $max)
    ->getResult();

return $query;
```

Comment: Are looking for the last 10 slowest _responses_ or the last 10 slowest _websites_ , - or the last 10 slowest responses for each website ?

Comment: 10 slowest `websites` by their last `ping`. The list above (arrays) are fine except that Twitter DE and Twitter UK where the most actual ping is actually offline, so it should not been shown.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic problem of "finding an information corresponding to the max row".

Without doing subrequest, this is done by doing a left join on the table itself :

```
SELECT w.id, s_last.id, s_last.response, w.name
FROM website w
JOIN ping s_last ON w.id = s.websiteId
# Left join on pings higher than us
LEFT JOIN ping s ON s.id > s_last.id
WHERE 
  # only take ping which has no higher ping
  s.id IS NULL
  AND
  # Filter out unreachable websites
  s_last.is_reachable = 1
ORDER BY s.response DESC
```

Given your exemple, Twitter DE and Twitter UK won't be in the result set, as they were not reached the last time we tried. (AFAIU, this is what you want)

Nevertheless, I don't know if it works well on data with many results. If performance is not well enough, try to save the last ping into another table.

Comment: `JOIN ping s_last ON w.id = s.website_id` doesn't work as it can't access the s.website_id before the defining `LEFT JOIN ping s`. Anyway I guess this was a typ so I replaced it with the correct s_last.website_id which finally let the query one. The result set therefore is sadly wrong as it just show's the row "Google Mail" with. Besides that the query is taking around 10 secs for 6.000 rows which is a sample data set. The real one would be much huger. I discussed my problem also with a friend and come up with a different query. See question post for it.